# chrome extension content script removeEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am new to programming and chrome extensions. I am not able to remove event listener from content script in my google extension.
AddeventListener is working and myFunc is called. myFunc is also getting called on removeEventListener.
It may be a trivial issue but I am not able to figure out. Thank you in advance for your help.

testScript.js:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('isOn',function(data) {
    var isOn =data.isOn;

    console.log('TESTSCRIPT:ACTIVATED, isOn: ' +isOn);
    if(isOn){
        console.log('add Event Listener');
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',myFunc);
    }
    else{
        console.log('remove Event Listener');
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup',myFunc);
    }
});

function myFunc(){
    console.log('my func activated');   
}
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('isOn',function(data){
        var isOn =data.isOn;
        console.log('value of isOn' ,isOn);

        if (isOn){
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'isOn' : false},function() {
                    console.log('The isOn is set to false.');
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'boy_off.png'});            
            });


        }
        else{
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'isOn' : true},function() {
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'boy.png'});

            });
        }
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
                    file:'testScript.js'
                });                     
    });


});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version":1,


  "name":"MyGC",
  "description":"This is chrome Extension",
  "version":"1.0",

  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"boy_off.png"   
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]

  },
  "permissions":[

    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",

   ],

}
```

Comment: You run the content script every time so myFunc gets a new reference each time so removeEventListener can't remove the old registered reference. You should use messaging or chrome.storage.onChanged instead of rerunning the content script.

Comment: could you help with an example?

Comment: `if (typeof myFunc !== 'function') window.myFunc = function() { .... your code }`

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object.  Each time you execute the script on document, it redefines myFunc as a new function.  This new function is not the same as the old one, in the previous execution.  So, removeEventListener(... myFunc) won't work.

One way to make it work is executing the content script once, and sending messages to it from background.js so the content script still has myFunc value.

Another way I didn't try: define myFunc only once in a content script.  Then run as many times as you wish another content script that invokes it, but don't define it again.

Comment: Thank you. 
1st way: could you give an example to implement it ?
2nd way: content scripts work in an isolated world. will content script be able to access another's function ?

Comment: All content script from the same extension and on the same tab work in the same isolated world.  It would be wise to first do an experiment to test this.